# How to build Razor views for various devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

At our company we build mobile websites for three categories of devices: 1- Hig-end devices such as smart phones, 2- Feature phones which are phones with 3G connectivity but weaker display features  and 3- Low-end mobiles that are old cheap mobiles which have a tiny screen and GSM internet connectivity.

To support these three types of devices we create three copies of each view and call them like View.cshtml,  View.Feature.cshtml and View.LowEnd.cshtml . Then based on the browser capabilities we decide that which view must be picked.

This approach has worked for us so far but the problem is that in an application with many views and partial views we end up having a huge number of .cshtml files that are impossible to manage. For example a site with 40 views will carry 120 .cshtml files!

Is there a better way of adapting a view for different devices?

Comment: What about using Media Queries in CSS 3?

Comment: If your company does such mobile websites and is in doubt in this endeavor, all the people there should read up on CSS3 Media QUeries. Even if you can't convert all of them in this way, you'll still a huge improvement in the number of views to maintain.

Comment: @AndreiV, will Media Queries help if the structure of the views are totally different among high-end, feature and low-end devices?!  Don't you think that CSS3 (which includes Media Queries) is not supported by old devices (which we call them low-end)?!

Comment: @Aref, I partially agree. I think that the default content should be directed to the (very) low end devices. The newer ones, that understand media queries, would not have a problem with hiding the low-quality "default" and showing the richer content. I hope that by "the structure of the views" you mean the choosing of HTML elements and their attributes and not a complete overhaul of the content.